# Do elements of a list inside a dictionary change it's order in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list inside a dictionary, it seems to change it's order in every iteration.

Consider this example,

```
a={ID: [value, [1,2,3,4,5,6]]}
```

When I access `a[ID][1]`, will it give `[1,2,3,4,5,6] (in order)` everytime I access this?

Comment: You claim that it changes its order in every iteration. Please provide a working example where this happens.

Comment: yes. it will give you that every time. The list has no knowledge that it is in a dictionary. If it is changing order, that's because something in the code is making it change order, but it's not the mere fact that it is part of some dict

Comment: @Finomnis No, it was just an example and it is a general question, I wanted to confirm it, before I proceed with writing my script.

Comment: @User I just ask because there must be a reason why you say 'it seems to change in every iteration'. In my opinion that statement is wrong, so I wonder where you got the impression from that it would.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a[ID][1] should give the same list in order each time.  Unless you change a somewhere else within your program.